# Trigger change event on hidden field when i don't know the moment of change with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden input in my HTML code and i want to know when the input value has changed.

```
<input type="hidden" id="myInputHidden" />
```

I can make something like this:

```
$('#myInputHidden').on('change', function() {
   alert('triggered');
});
```

In the first place, this doesn't work and in many posts i have read that i must trigger manually the event.

**The problem is that i don't know when (and where) the input value is changed so i cannot trigger that event.**

Comment: I don't see how that second snippet of code doesn't work, why do you think it does not?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to implement a `change` event to a hidden field is by *dirty-checking*, e.g:

```js
(function() {
  var myHidden = document.getElementById('myInputHidden'),
      currentValue = myHidden.value;

  setTimeout(function myHiddenOnChange() {
    if (myHidden.value !== currentValue) {
      currentValue = myHidden.value;    
      myHiddenChanged.call(myHidden);
    }

    setTimeout(myHiddenOnChange, 30);
  }, 30);

  function myHiddenChanged() {
    // that's your hidden field's 'change' event
  }
})();
```

---

I don't recommend it, but another approach is to override the `HTMLInputElement.prototype` descriptor:

```
(function() {
  var _htmlInputElementValue = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value'),
      _htmlInputElementValueSet = _htmlInputElementValue.set,
      _ev = document.createEvent('Event');

  _ev.initEvent('change', true, true);

  _htmlInputElementValue.set = function() {
    _htmlInputElementValueSet.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));

    if (this.type === 'hidden') {
      this.dispatchEvent(_ev);
    }
  }

  Object.defineProperty(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value', _htmlInputElementValue);
})();
```

Doing that, anytime someone changes the `value` property of a hidden field, it triggers the `change` event, so, if you're listening to that event, your code will start working.

Comment: Yes... that was an option.. but a dirty option that i want to use as a last resource

Comment: @Phoenix_uy it's the only one :)

Comment: @Phoenix_uy The EventListeners only work with user input, and since a hidden field never gets user interaction, it will never trigger any event, so you have two choices: create a method, eg `setHiddenValue`, that will change the `value` property of the hidden field and manually trigger the event (and then change your entire code to use that `setHiddenValue` method instead of directly changing the `value` property. And the other one is by dirty-checking, it's up to you.

Comment: @Phoenix_uy I updated my answer with another solution for you.